Why does the triangle inequality work while proving $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ limits .
For instance , consider the relatively simple limit
$$\lim_{x\to 2} x^2-4=0$$
Now to attempt to find $\delta$ in terms of $\varepsilon$
so
$$|x-2||x+2|<\varepsilon$$
Using the triangle inequality
$$|x-2|(|x-2|+4)<\varepsilon$$
now letting  $\delta<1$ this gives us
$$\delta < \frac{\varepsilon}{5}$$
However, how can we be sure that the following isn't true
$$|x-2|(|x+2|)<\varepsilon<|x-2|(|x-2|+4)$$

"However, how can we be sure that the following isn't true $|x−2|(|x+2|)<ε<|x−2|(|x−2|+4).$" There exists a delta such that $|x−2|(|x−2|+4)$ will be less than $\epsilon.$  And if $|x−2|(|x−2|+4)$ is less than $\epsilon$ then we know that $|x^2-4|$ will be less than $\epsilon.$

I don't follow?

I;m asking why isn't my concern valid

What is the functionality of the last line? We want the first inequality to be true. What is the second inequality for?

I'm asking  how do we know that $|x-2|(|x+2|)<\varepsilon<|x-2|(|x-2|+4)$ isn't true

Maybe it is true, why does it matter? If the second inequality was the other way round, then the first inequality would be automatically true.

By choosing $\delta = \min\left{1,\frac\varepsilon 5\right}$ with your freedom, and for all $\lvert x-2\rvert < \delta$, you can be sure that the inequality is instead:
$$\begin{align*}
\lvert x-2\rvert &< \frac\varepsilon5\
\lvert x-2\rvert + 4 &< 1+4 =5\
\lvert x-2\rvert (\lvert x-2\rvert + 4) &< \varepsilon
\end{align*}$$

We must find a $\delta$
$|x-2||x+2| < \epsilon$ when $|x-2| < \delta$
$|x-2||x+2|=|x-2||x-2+4| \le |x-2|(|x-2| + 4)$ by the triangle inequality.  This will always be true.
Yes, it is the case that for some value of $\delta$ it may be the case that $|x-2||x+2| < \epsilon < |x-2|(|x-2| + 4).$  But, we don't care about that.
We just need to show that a delta exists $|x-2||x+2|<\epsilon$ and we don't need to find the maximal value of $\delta$
If $\delta < \min(1,\frac {\epsilon}{5})$
$|x-2|(|x-2| + 4)\le 5\delta < \epsilon$ and therefore $|x^2-4| \le |x-2|(|x-2| + 4) < \epsilon$

Frame change.
Your last question is irrelevant in the final proof. What you have written so far is how you discovered a good candidate for $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$. Now your job is to write the full argument starting from "If $|x - 2| < \epsilon/5$ and $|x - 2| < 1$ ..." to conclude what you want to know about $|x^2 - 4|$.
None of what you wrote in the question is part of that proof.

I don't understand why I can use the triangle inequality

Who claims that you cannot use the triangle inequality?

@JoséCarlosSantos . No one, I've explained why I think I can't in my question.
